# Watch blocking call nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, blocking, nonblocking

I'm trying to connect to a 3rd party library, that has a function that can block. I would like to use it, but without blocking. Is it possible to wrap a blocking call that I don't have the control of, to make it async?

```
// calling this function will block the nodejs thread
blockingCall();
```

What I would like would be something like this.

```
// wrapper for the blocking call
var wrapper = wrapBlockingCall(blockingCall);
wrapper.on('complete', function() {});
```

Is this possible? Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but I'd advise you to not do it. If you want something to happen after a synchronous call, place a statement after it. I'm not entirely sure why you want to 'watch' a synchronous call. We might need more information on either the library you are using, or the problem you are facing (not what you want to do).

Comment: so, the issue is that, the client library is a multithreaded c library, i've made a nodejs wrapper for it. because the way it works, it requires the client(nodejs) todo a blocking call, while itself it calls a function in the client(nodejs) that should result in unblocking the first call. since node is single threaded, this is just a deadlock. i was wondering if I could get around this transforming the c call into a async call, and put all the logic after that in the callback. I hope it makes sense

Comment: You aren't going to make synchronous code asynchronous by putting it in a callback. You will just be delaying the blocking call until the next event tick. Consider spawning a child process and waiting for that to complete or using fibers if all else fails.

Comment: it starts to make sense. installed fibers, made a fiber wrapping the blocking call. though it doesn't seem to have an event emitter interface, that would allow me to execute some other code when the fiber finishes.

Comment: will actually put the depending code inside the fiber after the blocking call. could you please answer the question and i'll accept it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make a blocking JavaScript code non-blocking in Node.js - the mechanism which Node uses for its non-blocking behaviour is implemented in the C/C++ layer, which in turn is used only when doing I/O operations (reading from disk, networking etc.).

In reality, every line of JavaScript your program uses will be executed one-by-one, because it is always executed on the same thread, no matter what you do.

The only option I see is to execute the offending code in a separate Node process using the built-in [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) module. However, this will have significant performance impact, even bigger one if the code needs to be executed frequently.

**Note:**

After reading the comments under your question, it seems that you are actually the author of the blocking function, which in turn calls a C API which performs blocking I/O. There are ways of calling C functions which would normally block in a manner which does not block the upper JavaScript layer.

While I am not a C expert, I think this is accomplished using the *libuv* library included in Node - have a look at the [addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) documentation for more info.

Comment: Good info. Never tried to do something like this myself but I was always under the assumption that any external/native libs would be executed in a separate thread.

Comment: Regarding performance impact though- the only reason I can think of for using external C/C++ code would be for relatively heavy compute operations (crypto perhaps), something that node.js would probably not be the best choice for.

Comment: The performance impact I mentioned was about spawning a new process every time you would need to call your function. Using C/C++ addons has some performance impact as well (your code needs to pass values across languages), but it's relatively minor.